# Organize imports for Eclipse plugin files

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I've been playing around with Eclipse plugin development in Java and have noticed that classes referenced by my plugin.xml refuse to automatically include imports for classes within my source folder.

Any file that is not referenced by plugin.xml works fine with organize imports or quick fix. But when the file is referenced by plugin.xml, I have to type in the package import manually. I'm guessing this is a feature to help you manage dependencies, but I don't want it to work like that.

Is there any setting that can change this behaviour?

Comment: This sounds very odd, I can't imagine why being referenced by `plugin.xml` would  cause this. Does control-shift-M (Add Import) work?

Comment: It was very odd and it was only occurring on the specific files that were referenced by plugin.xml.

Unfortunately, I've deleted the project and I've since switched to Scala. With Scala I no longer have this issue. Actually, I've been pleasantly surprised with Scala as a whole :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some of the referenced plugin packages will not be exported . Instead of manually importing the  packages .

Try this ,

Under `Runtime` tab of the referenced plugin plugin.xml  export the packages so that it is visible in the referencing plugin.

Hope this helps !!!